# How to return a bytes value in a cherry py request body

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, cherrypy

I have a postgres table that contains a `bytea` column.  This column contains an image.

The SqlAlchemy model has this column defined as a `LargeBinary`.  I've also tried to using `BLOB`, but It didn't change a thing.

I can easily retrieve a value from the database and what I get is a variable of type `bytes`.

How can I jsonify that bytes array?  I need the json value so I can return it in the cherrypy request body like so :

```
data = { 'id_image': image.id_image, 'image': image.value }
```

Comment: JSON cannot contain control characters so you have to escape them somehow. The easiest way is to base64-encode your raw binary, but that requires 33% overhead. Why do you need to return binary in JSON anyway? Could you not return the image as `Content-Type: image/jpeg` or something?

Comment: You can use base64 encoding and represent your blob as [data URI](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)

Comment: @Kinetic plz mark my answer as correct if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you need to show that image in a browser or similar software.

Normally you can use [Data URI](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) when embedding image as a string into a web page. Modern browsers know how to decode it back.

Also I'm assuming you have a PNG image. If your case is different, feel free to change `image/png` to something, which matches your needs.

Here's how you can generate data URI using Python.

*This example uses Python 3.6 syntax:*

```
import base64

img_id = image.id_image
img_base64_encoded = base64.b64encode(image.value).decode('ascii')
img_type = 'image/png'  # Use some smart image type guessing if applicable

img_data_uri = f'data:{img_type};base64,{img_base64_encoded}'

img_data = {
    'id': image.id_image,
    'data_uri': img_data_uri
}
```